# Who took this photograph in March 1891 Missouri?

Tags: photo-identification, photo, 1890s, missouri

I'm trying to identify the photographer that took this picture around March 1891 in Blue Springs, Jackson, Missouri, from the faint imprint on the back of the photo cardboard holder.[image: Back of photo]

I can make out the initials J. H. before the last name and a studio name appears to be Blue Car____.

Here is the front:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the only photographer I found with initials J. H.

Name:   James H Schwartz

Residence Year:     1887

Street address:     ws Broad

Residence Place:    Kansas City, Jackson County, Missouri, USA

Occupation:     Photographer

Publication Title:  Kansas City, Missouri, City Directory, 1887

Answer (score 4):

I have tried to remove as much of the paper color as possible, as a means of highlighting what was written:

My best interpretation is "J. H. Gold":

[image: J H Gold, maybe?]

Comment: Another thing to consider is the alignment. Assuming "Photographer" and "Blue Car" are center-aligned, it would make sense that the photographer's name would be, too. In that case the last name might be "Goldman" or some variant. (Of course, it's a speculative statement given that the text is illegible on the right.)

Comment: "Goodman" is also a candidate.